# JSF button is not working on first click after adding ID attribute

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have the below code in my JSF page for a button.

```
<h:commandButton title="#{msg['dealsheet.button.accept']}"
styleClass="btnIcon iconDSAccept jqTooltip iconDSAcceptNPD"
onclick="return checkForPopup(this,'#{ds.dealSheetType}','#{ds.dealSheetNo}');"
action="#{dealSheetBean.saveDealSheetOnOverWrite()}"
actionListener="#{dealSheetBean.assignSelectedDeal(ds.dealSheetNo)}">
</h:commandButton>
```

It was working fine previously. But after adding the attribute **id="iconDSAccept#{ds.dealSheetNo}"**  to **h:commandButton** the button is not working on the first click i am getting log as 12:55:27,144 `WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.`. When I click for the second time it is working fine.

Can anyone advice me why this is happening and how to resolve this ?

Comment: The problem is with the text **#{ds.dealSheetNo}**. After removing this, the button is working fine. :) But I don't know why it is not working on the first click with this code snippet. If someone knows the answer, please post it.

Comment: what is the reason you are generating dynamic id is this inside some loop?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Yes. The code is inside a loop. Inside the tag **ui:repeat**

Comment: As you dont tell what exactly your code look like .Please check Point 9 of this question's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value/2120183#2120183